# Using dplyr within a loop to summarise several data.frame variables

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, nse

I want to summarise several columns from a data.frame. The grouping and summary was achieved with `dplyr`, as in the example below.

```
df = data.frame (time = rep(c("day", "night"), 10) , 
    who =rep(c("Paul", "Simon"), each=10) , 
    var1 = runif(20, 5, 15), var2 = runif(20, 10, 12), var3 = runif(20, 2, 7), var4 = runif(20, 1, 3))
```

Writting the function I need

`quantil_x = function (var, num) {
    quantile(var, num, na.rm=T)
}`

Using it at `var1` and exporting

```
percentiles = df %>% group_by(time, who) %>% summarise(
    P0 = quantil_x (var1, 0),
    P25 = quantil_x (var1, .25),
    P75 = quantil_x (var1, .75)
    )
write.table(percentiles, file = "summary_var1.csv",row.names=FALSE, dec=",",sep=";")
```

What I want is to repeat this same task for `'var2'`, `'var3'` and `'var4'`. I have tried to run a loop with no success to perform this task multiple times. Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to handle distinct calls of variables within the code. That is, within the loop I have tried to use `summarise_()`, tried to use `get()` inside the fuction `quantil_x()`  or within `summarise`, also `as.name` but none of this worked.

I'm pretty sure this is a bad coding skill issue, but that's all I came up with so far. Here is an example of what I tried to do:

```
list = c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")
for (i in list){
percentiles = df %>% group_by(time, who) %>% summarise(
    P0 = quantil_x (get(i), 0),
    P25 = quantil_x (get(i), .25),
    P75 = quantil_x (get(i), .75)
    )
write.table(percentiles, file = paste0("summary_",i,".csv",row.names=FALSE, dec=",",sep=";")
}
```

I read this [post](http://www.milanor.net/blog/aggregation-dplyr-summarise-summarise_each/), but didn't help much on my case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `gather()`

```
percentiles = df %>%
gather(Var,Value,var1,var2,var3) %>%
 group_by(Var,time, who) %>%
 summarise(
    P0 = quantil_x (Value, 0),
    P25 = quantil_x (Value, .25),
    P75 = quantil_x (Value, .75)
    )
```

Comment: This approach has the advantage of creating more lines than columns. Additionally it sorts lines in a more logical way than the other one sorts columns.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `summarise_each()`

```
df %>% 
 group_by(time, who) %>% 
 summarise_each(funs (`0` = quantile(., 0, na.rm=T),
                      `25`= quantile(., .25, na.rm = T),
                      `75`= quantile(., .75, na.rm = T)))
```

Comment: Thansk I didn't know one could use `.` like this.